# Testing more than one same link rspec capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I have two About Us links in the homepage (one in the header and one in the footer of the page). I need to test that both links point to the same About Us page.

I have written test in rspec like this inside the describe block:

```
it { should have_link('About Us', href: aboutus_path) }
```

However this test does not give error if there is at least one link is ok in the page. I need something that checks for both links and it should give error if any one of the links has been changed.

Thanks in advance for the help Guys!

Comment: you should use the `all` method with css or xpath, then count

Comment: Thanks for the help apneadiving, this worked for me:  
`expect(page).to have_selector('a', text: 'About Us', count: 2)`

Comment: ok cool, did not know :)